# jQuery .hover only when comments div is collapse

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I just began using jQuery and need some help on the following.

I have my comments box on a fixed div, it is collapsed as long as the user is not at the bottom of the page. When the user scrolls down, the comments box slowly appears along with comments.

What I want to achieve now is that, as long as the comments box is collapsed, I want to apply a .hover effect on it. So when the user hovers it, the div grows in size.

This is what I have so far:

```
var secondary = jQuery(".comments-holder");

var magicFooter = function(){
    var scrollBottom = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height();
    var maxHeight =  jQuery("#disqus_thread").height(); 
    jQuery("#colophon").css("height", maxHeight);  
    var mediumHeight = 120;
    var minHeight = 60;

    secondary.height(maxHeight - (jQuery(document).height() - scrollBottom));

    if (secondary.height() <= minHeight) {

            secondary.css("height",minHeight);
            secondary.hover(function(){
                    jQuery(this).css("height",mediumHeight);
            },
            function(){
                jQuery(this).css("height",minHeight);
            });

        } 

}; 
magicFooter();

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    magicFooter();
});
```

The .hover effect is not working as intended. I want to apply it only when the div is at minHeight.

Comment: Did you mean `jQuery(".comments-holder").mouseenter(function() {
    magicFooter();
});` ?

Comment: No, I did not mean it like that.

Comment: So, nobody can help me out?

Comment: Maybe me or someone else can but can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your `html` so it would be more clear.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014739/how-to-stop-hover-from-triggering-inside-an-if-statement I just needed to express myself better.