# How to stop .hover from triggering inside an if statement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am trying to stop a .hover action whenever a div changes height.

This is the code I have so far:

```
if (secondary.height() <= 300) {
    secondary.css("height",300);
    secondary.hover(function(){
        jQuery('.comments-holder').css("height",mediumHeight);
    },
    function(){             
        jQuery('.comments-holder').css("height",minHeight);     
    });
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

The problem I am having is that .hover is being triggered no matter what the if statement implies.

Comment: move the if statement to inside the hover event handler so it only gets handled if the condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the height inside the hover function.

> ```
> secondary.hover(function(){
>     if (secondary.height() <= 300) {
>       jQuery('.comments-holder').css("height",mediumHeight);
>       }
> },
> function(){    
>     if (secondary.height() <= 300) {         
>      jQuery('.comments-holder').css("height",minHeight);    
>     } 
> });
> ```